# Do View Indexes are more susceptible to lock contention?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view, locking

On several posts here on SO I see warnings regarding the creation of an index on a view, that may result in a lock contention.

Some of those posts link to this blog post: [Be ready to drop your indexed view](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/02/be-ready-to-drop-your-indexed-view.aspx), which I read, but haven't found an answer to the following question:

Is there something that makes operations on a view's index more susceptible to lock contention than operations on "regular" indexes?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why indexes on views can be more prone to lock contention issues - sadly these are the reasons who views are useful :-(. Those I'm most familiar with are as follows:

1) Indexed views are often used to provide summary information - select x,y,sum(z) from MyTable group by x,y - where seperate actions update different rows with the same values of x and y then this can result in a clash

2) Where an indexed view relates to more than one table then locking issues can also occur - this risk can be reduced if it is possible to control access order in all transacted operations that related to the two tables (i.e. always lock Table1 before Table2). Sometimes its possible to get around this issue by including denormalised value in a single table and then building the view on just that table.

Indexed views are great - but carry with them substantial risk.